# Concatenating child items to parent items

Tags: javascript, oop, extjs, extjs4.2

I cannot find any documentation on Sencha's site that deals with the following scenario:

### Cube (Base class)

```
Ext.define('example.ext.Cube', {
    sides: [
        'one',
        'two',
        'three',
        'four',
        'five',
        'six']
});
```

Which of the two versions below is the standard way of concatenating new properties to existing ones? Both work the same way, but I feel as though Version A makes more sense

### Dodecahedron (Child class)

#### Version A

```
Ext.define('example.ext.Dodecahedron', {
    extend: 'example.ext.Cube',
    sides: [
        'seven',
        'eight',
        'nine',
        'ten',
        'eleven',
        'twelve'],

    constructor: function () {
        var me = this;
        // Alternatively: Ext.apply(me.sides, me.superclass.sides);
        me.sides = me.superclass.sides.concat(me.sides);
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

#### Version B

```
Ext.define('example.ext.Dodecahedron', {
    extend: 'example.ext.Cube',
    constructor: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me.sides, [
            'seven',
            'eight',
            'nine',
            'ten',
            'eleven',
            'twelve']);
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

## Working Example

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.ns('example.ext');

  Ext.define('example.ext.Cube', {
    sides: [
      'one',
      'two',
      'three',
      'four',
      'five',
      'six'
    ],

    roll: function() {
      return this.sides[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides.length)];
    }
  });

  Ext.define('example.ext.Dodecahedron', {
    extend: 'example.ext.Cube',
    sides: [
      'seven',
      'eight',
      'nine',
      'ten',
      'eleven',
      'twelve'
    ],

    constructor: function() {
      var me = this;
      me.sides = me.superclass.sides.concat(me.sides);
      me.callParent(arguments);
    }
  });

  var die12 = Ext.create('example.ext.Dodecahedron');

  window.roll = function() {
    var side = die12.roll();
    var indefiniteArticle = side.match(/^[aeiou](?![n])/) ? 'an' : 'a';
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Ext.String.format('You rolled {0} {1}.', indefiniteArticle, side);
  }
});
```

```css
.vertical {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#dice {
  background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/48x48-free-object-icons/48/Dice.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
#result {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/builds/ext-core.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="dice" value="" onclick="roll();" />
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <div style="position:relative;height:64px;width:256px;">
    <div class="vertical">
      <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use Ext.apply in initComponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410667/why-use-ext-apply-in-initcomponent)

Comment: Not really, I am describing a situation where I have a custom config and I want to know if it is OK to redefine the property in a child class to extend the super-classes' config. I cannot find documentation describing my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Ext JS 5 config system allows inherited configs that are prototype chained. In 4.x you have to roll your own though.

I'd recommend going with something like your Version A, it's going to be less painful in the long run.